# Remote command failure even after unencrypted traffic is true

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-4.0

I am trying to open remote PSSession from one PC to another. Both PCs are in the LAN and reachable, but whenever I try to enter PSSession the following error occurs:

```
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server pc2 failed with the
following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request.
Unencrypted traffic is currently disabled in the client configuration.
Change the client configuration and try the request again. For more
information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic. At
line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName pc2 -Authentication Basic -Credential admin
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (pc2:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

I have set `AllowUnencrypted` to true in both

> WSMan::localhost\Client

and

> WSMan::localhost\Service

location on the remote PC, but still getting the same error. Are there other settings I need to update?

Comment: Please show the output of `winrm get winrm/config/client`.

Comment: client or remote pc?